# API for looking up Gmail user's public full name?

Tags: email, gmail, google-plus, gmail-imap

Is there an API to look up the same information that I can get from Gmail if I type someone's email address into Gmail's search bar and hit search? For most Gmail addresses, this shows me the person's full name.

I ask for people's email address when they sign up on my website, but not for their names. I'd like to add a personal greeting to the emails that I send out. Note that people have NOT signed up using Google+.

Comment: What does this have to do with IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the new [People API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.connections.list?resourceName=people%252Fme&_h=3&).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this requires that the person has given my app permission to see their info. I'm looking for a way to look up _anyone's_ public information - the same that I can see if I type someone's email address into my Gmail search bar.